# The inverse of a Matrix with a square off-diagonal matrix partition

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

So… I’m trying to find the origins of the unitary bounded lemma and I have a doubt on a matrix inversion of a matrix with a square off-diagonal matrix partition.

Following the reference:

Boyd, S., Balakrishnan, V., & Kabamba, P. (1989). A bisection method for computing the H∞ norm of a transfer matrix and related problems. Mathematics of Control, Signals, and Systems (MCSS), 2(3), 207-219.

Having a set of real matrices $\{A,B,C,D\}$ with sizes $n\times n$ , $n\times p$, $m\times n$, $m\times p$

Equation (4) gives the following relation:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & -A^T\end{bmatrix}  +
 \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & -C^T \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} -D  &  \gamma I_v \\ \gamma I_u  &  -D^T \end{bmatrix} ^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} C &  0 \\ 0  &  B^T \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} A-BR^{-1}D^TC  &  -\gamma BR^{-1}B^T \\ \gamma C^TS^{-1}C  &  -A^T + C^TDR^{-1}B^T \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $R=(D^TD - \gamma^2 I)$ and $S=(DD^T - \gamma ^2 I)$

this only stands as true in the case:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} -D  &  \gamma I_v \\ \gamma I_u  &  -D^T \end{bmatrix} ^{-1}
= \begin{bmatrix} -R^{-1}D^T  &  -\gamma R^{-1} \\ -\gamma S^{-1}  &  -DR^{-1}              
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My question is : how can I obtain the inverse of  a matrix with a square off-diagonal matrix partition as the inverse that appears in this case?

Has someone ever had a problem like this one?, 
Is this a trivial question? 
where do I search?... tank you

Somehow the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix} - D^T  &  -\gamma I_u \\ -\gamma I_v  &  -D \end{bmatrix}

Gives the idea of a generalization of a transpose cofactor matrix… still it feels wrong… also… the “determinant” has two diferent values and appears as a product form both right and left sides.

**I have to clarify**

the provided identity in such reference is true.
you can see that:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -D  &  \gamma I_v \\ \gamma I_u  &  -D^T \end{bmatrix} ^{-1}
= \begin{bmatrix} -R^{-1}D^T  &  -\gamma R^{-1} \\ -\gamma S^{-1}  &  -DR^{-1}              
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You can prove it by

$$
\begin{bmatrix} -R^{-1}D^T  &  -\gamma R^{-1} \\ -\gamma S^{-1}  &  -DR^{-1}              
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} -D  &  \gamma I_v \\ \gamma I_u  &  -D^T \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} R^{-1}D^TD-\gamma^2R^{-1}  &  -\gamma R^{-1}D^T +\gamma R^{-1}D^T \\ \gamma S^{-1}D - \gamma DR^{-1} &  -\gamma^2S^{-1} + DR^{-1}D^T              
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As you can easily prove:$ R^{-1}D^TD - R^{-1}\gamma^2 = R^{-1}(D^TD-\gamma^2 I) = R^{-1}R = I $ .

Also $ -\gamma R^{-1}D^T + \gamma R^{-1}D^T = 0 $ .

And using the inverse series expansion we can see that:

$$
\gamma S^{-1}D - \gamma DR^{-1} = \gamma (DD^T-\gamma^2 I)^{-1}D -\gamma D(D^TD-\gamma^2 I)^{-1}
$$
$$
 = -\gamma (\gamma^2 I- DD^T)^{-1}D +\gamma D(\gamma^2 I - D^TD)^{-1} 
$$
$$
=\gamma[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (DD^T)^{i-1} (\frac{1}{\gamma^2})^{i}]D - \gamma D[\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (D^TD)^{j-1} (\frac{1}{\gamma^2})^{j}]
$$
$$
=\gamma[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (DD^T)^{i-1}D (\frac{1}{\gamma^2})^{i}] - \gamma [\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} D(D^TD)^{j-1} (\frac{1}{\gamma^2})^{j}]=0
$$

And we can also see that:

$$
-\gamma^2S^{-1} + DR^{-1}D^T=   \gamma^2 (\gamma^2 I- DD^T)^{-1} - D(\gamma^2 I - D^TD)^{-1}D^T 
$$
$$
=\gamma^2 [\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (DD^T)^{i-1} (\frac{1}{\gamma^2})^{i}]-
D [\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (D^TD)^{j-1} (\frac{1}{\gamma^2})^{j}]D^T=(\frac{\gamma^2}{\gamma^2})(DD^T)^{0}=I
$$

**I Remark**

My question is how do they obtain the inverse?...

Is it some generalized Kramer rule, why do I need to make the product from both sides... Anyway... thank you!

Comment: Can't you just multiply through the matrix being inverted on both sides to verify? eg $C^{-1} = A \iff I = AC = CA$? Does that not give the right result? Haha then you can contact the authors :)

Comment: Also you have a couple of sign errors. Double check, that could be the missing detail too.

Comment: I know the inverse is correct... I add a prove from the left side and can be eaisily checked from right side to... is just that... how do I obtain it?

Comment: Based on the meta-reputation of the authors, the derivation is most likely not trivial. :) Here's what I have for a start: Suppose $M = [D, I; I, D^T]$ and $M^{-1} = [A,B;C,E]$. Then since $MM^{-1} = I$, you can get a sequence of relations like $C = (DA)^{-1}$, $D^TC = A$, $E = DB$, and $B = (D^TE)^{-1}$. Probably $M^{-1} M = I$ gives a few more. It doesn't seem to exactly yield their solution, but maybe can give some insight?

Comment: I expect this follows from the [blockwise matrix inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to just do $\gamma = 1$. I think it's not hard to extend it to arbitrary $\gamma$, following these steps.

First, note that we can "rotate" this matrix, e.g.

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-D & I \\ I & -D^T 
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
I & -D \\ -D^T & I 
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & I \\ I & 0 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
and if $M$ is the inverse of the left hand side, then

$$M = \left(\left[
\begin{matrix}
I & -D \\ -D^T & I 
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & I \\ I & 0 
\end{matrix}
\right]\right)^{-1}
=\left[
\begin{matrix}
I & -D \\ -D^T & I 
\end{matrix}
\right]^{-1}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 & I \\ I & 0 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

So I'm just going to find the inverse of the "rotated" matrix. Note that this matrix is symmetric, so I know the inverse is also symmetric. Let's say the inverse is 
$$
N = \left[
\begin{matrix}
A & B \\ B^T & C 
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$
Then $I = N^{-1}N = $ 
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
A-DB^T & B^T-D^TA \\ DC-B & C-D^TB 
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
which implies the following four relations

$$A-DB^T = I$$
$$C-D^TB = I$$
$$D^TA =B^T$$
$$B = DC$$

Using the first and third to solve for $A$ and the second and fourth to solve for $C$ gives
$$
A-DD^TA = I \iff A = (I-DD^T)^{-1}
$$
$$
C-D^TDC - I \iff C - (I-D^TD)^{-1}.
$$
I think that should yield that relation you have.